Options with plus instead of minus
Some command line tools allow for options with + besides -.
ImageMagick - for example - allows for the transparent option to invert the matched pixels.
I'd like to do something similar in perl.
Is that feasible? are there options to do that in Getopt::Long or would that be feasible with some subclassing - ideally of Getopt::Long::Descriptive?
And is that a good idea at all?

See the prefix_pattern option for Getopt::Long. By default, + is an acceptable option for starting an argument.

Re "is that a good idea at all?", Inventing new option styles is a horrible idea.

I created a script using + instead of -, using the Configure method of Getopt::Long:
Getopt::Long::Configure('prefix=+');

as documented here and specifically prefix, prefix_pattern and long_prefix_pattern.

And is that a good idea at all?

In some ways, I regret my decision to do so.

See also Getopt::Long::Configure('getopt_compat'), which allows either - or + to start options. This is enabled by default unless the POSIXLY_CORRECT environment variable is set. 'prefix=+' should allow + and disallow -. See also prefix_pattern, which defaults to --|-|+ or --|-. Feel free to add this information to your answer.

@ikegami you can use prefix_pattern A Perl pattern that identifies the strings that introduce options. Default is --|-|+ unless environment variable POSIXLY_CORRECT has been set, in which case it is --|-.

The op wishes to know which prefix was used. I don't see how that allows that.

Ha! didn't catch that! (I am the op, but that doesn't excuse me). I'll have to do some more thinking and trying

Getopt::Long doesn't support that style of negatable option, but it does support one I prefer.
Instead of making +foo the opposite of -foo, it makes --no-foo and --nofoo the opposite of --foo.
An option of type ! is negatable.
For example, the following defines verbose as a negatable option:
'verbose!' => \$opt_verbose


This will set $opt_verbose to a true value if --verbose is used.
This will set $opt_verbose to a false value if --no-verbose or --noverbose is used.
Last one wins out if more than one is used.



And is that a good idea at all?

I don't have any problems with negatable options.
As for the specific style of negatable option you requested,

I've always found +foo to mean "no foo" confusing. I associate + with adding or enabling.
Using - and + means you can't have option bundling.

The style used by Getopt::Long has neither of these defects.

Actually the goal in my use case is to have it mean exactly adding or enabling, like in "+volume" and "-volume"

Wouldn't something like --volume=n (where is a number from 0 to 100) make more sense?

You could also do --volume=+ or --volume=-

Yep. I'm playing with options to see what works best. Obviously +v and -v are shortest.
But thanks a lot for taking the time to answer.

Welcome. +v and -v are cute, but I don't see how Getopt::Long can be used to support them. (Getopt::Long will let you enter them, but it ill treat them identically.) -v + and -v -  are not much longer.

When I read that user-defined callbacks receive an object, I thought it might provide the prefix in an undocumented way. But it doesn't
